# How to Create Master script file to run mysql scripts

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

#### I want to create DB structure for my application in mysql, I have some 100 scripts which will create tables , sp, functions in different schemas.

#### Please suggest how can i run script only one after other and how can i stop if previous script failed. I am using MySQL 5.6 version.

I am currrently runnning them using a text file.

`mysql> source /mypath/CreateDB.sql`

which contains

`tee /logout/session.txt

source /mypath/00-CreateSchema.sql

source /mypath/01-CreateTable1.sql

source /mypath/01-CreateTable2.sql

source /mypath/01-CreateTable3.sql`

#### But they are running simultaniously and I have Foreign key in below tables due to which it is giving error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scripts are not running simultaneously. The mysql client does not execute in a multi-threaded manner.

But it's possible that you are sourcing the scripts in an order that causes foreign keys to reference tables that you haven't defined yet, and this is a problem.

You have two possible fixes for this problem:

- Create the tables in the order to avoid this problem.
- Create all the tables without their foreign keys, then run another script that contains `ALTER TABLE ADD FOREIGN KEY`... statements.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will go with second option I will place constraints in one script and include last in my execution order.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a Python function to execute SQL files:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Download it at http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/?source=dlp
# Tutorials: http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html
#            http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlpython/
import MySQLdb as mdb 

import datetime, time

def run_sql_file(filename, connection):
    '''
    The function takes a filename and a connection as input
    and will run the SQL query on the given connection  
    '''
    start = time.time()

    file = open(filename, 'r')
    sql = s = " ".join(file.readlines())
    print "Start executing: " + filename + " at " + str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")) + "\n" + sql 
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql)    
    connection.commit()

    end = time.time()
    print "Time elapsed to run the query:"
    print str((end - start)*1000) + ' ms'



def main():    
    connection = mdb.connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'password', 'database_name')
    run_sql_file("my_query_file.sql", connection)    
    connection.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I haven't tried it with stored procedure or large SQL statements. Also if you have SQL files containing several SQL queries, you might have to split(";") to extract each query and call `cursor.execute(sql)` for each query. Feel free to edit this answer to incorporate these improvements.

Comment: What if the file is >1GB in size? What if the script contains statements with ";" inside comments, or inside quoted strings, or inside a CREATE PROCEDURE statement? What if the script has mysql client builtin statements like DELIMITER?

Comment: Even if this script worked, it can do nothing to fix the OP's errors. His problem is due to the order in which he creates tables.